# Force empty strings to raise exception when using Crystal's JSON.mapping macro

Tags: crystal-lang

Is it possible to force `JSON.mapping` to raise a parse exception if/when a string member is present, but its value is the empty string?

I've tried using the available options (`presence`, `nilable`, etc.) to no avail. I've also experimented with writing a custom converter -- it looks like this will probably work -- but I want to make sure I'm not missing a simple solution to what seems like it should be a pretty common use case.

Comment: Raising on an empty string doesn't seem like a common use case to me. Just empty or blank too? (that is, only spaces). It seems your requirements are very specific, and that's why you'll need a specific converter for this, there's no other way around it.

Comment: @asterite I'd argue that it is a pretty common use case. For example, I'm seeing it because a user did not enter a value in an HTML form field.

Comment: I think you should validate your model once it's parsed. You shouldn't validate it at the parsing level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to tack custom validation code onto the method produced by `JSON.mapping`

```
require "json"

struct Foo
  JSON.mapping(field: String)

  def initialize(pull : JSON::PullParser)
    previous_def
    raise JSON::Error.new("empty field") if field.empty?
  end
end

Foo.from_json(%({"field": ""}))
```

Comment: Thanks! I've yet to get my custom converter working, so I may end up running with something inspired by this.